# Discord bot AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord.py

I was messing around with making a bot, but I can't figure out how to ban someone...

```
    if message.content.upper().startswith('CHILL BAN'):
        if "447929519945416734" in [role.id for role in 
message.author.roles] or "448191759739256842" in [role.id for role in 
message.author.roles] or message.author.id == "218156043799101452":

            await bot.kick(message.mentions[0].name)
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, "Someone has been 
banned!")
            #["<@356065937318871041>"]

        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, "You do not have 
sufficient privileges.")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This error means `role` or `author` is a string. Try printing out the values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the on_message event for a ban command
use the command handler instead

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await bot.ban(user)
    await bot.say(f"{user.name} Just got banned")
# Do extra stuff here if you want
```

Comment: Not everyone uses ext.commands, regardless though, it may be worth pointing out that his issue is caused by using `Client.kick` on the user's name instead of the user object itself...